# Drawer content are unexpectedly shown when the device screen is rotated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

I have Scaffold with drawer content. Also I set attribute configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest file.
When I rotate screen from portrait orientation to album, drawer content unexpectedly show on the screen. How I can prevent from such behavior (I don't need to see drawer content after screen rotation)?

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Scaffold(
                drawerContent = {
                    Text(text = "drawer")
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "body",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I started app the screen is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkubj.png)

And after the screen is rotated, the drawer is shown, why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eds3Y.png)